# Improving efficiency on returning duplicate numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance

I am trying to improve the efficiency of my code,

The purpose is to simply obtain the duplicates that is output, in this case i have chosen the #1, to be counted, so for example given N = 3, 11^3 = 1331, would return 2, as we can count two 1's in the output.

Naturally when dealing with a larger power (where N is a large number), this reduces the efficiency drastically.

I managed to produce a quick but inefficient rough solution, that seems to work, but what could i do to improve the code and its efficiency?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Solution {

    private static int num = 11;

    public static int solution(int n) {

        int counter = 0;
        String compare = "1";
        double answer = Math.round(Math.pow(num, n));
        System.out.println(answer);

        String s = String.valueOf(answer);
        String[] parts = s.split("");

        for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
            if (parts[i].equals(compare)){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        return counter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        solution(8);
        solution(3);
    }
}
```

Any help in improving my understanding of the techniques of writing more efficient code would be much appreciated as well as improvements to the code example above.

Comment: you will get more/better response for a question like this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @sleepToken

Comment: `Math.pow(num, n)` does not take more time for bigger _n_ values. You can use `toCharArray` instead of `split` and compare char instead of String,  which would be better. All in all there is little to gain in either case, since you would sooner run out of decimal precision then spending any time in such calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Split and regex is slow (replaceAll), but replaceAll is short:

```
    counter = s.replaceAll("[^" + compare + "]", "").length();
```

or

```
    char[] parts = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (parts[i] == '1') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

or

```
    for (char ch : parts) {
        if (parts[i] == '1') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
```